# Unable to get data using Fetch API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I've the following function that makes and api call and gets data.

```
export function getUserData(url){

  return fetch(url, { credentials : 'include'})
              .then((response) => { return response.json()})
              .then((data) =>{ return new User(data.uid, data.givenName, data.familyName)})
}
```

This is my User object.

```
class User{
  constructor(uid, givenName, familyName){

    this.uid = yguid;
    this.givenName = givenName;
    this.familyName = familyName;
  }
}
export default User;
```

Now in my react component I'm trying to instantiate the User object.

```
class Header extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { fullName: null, yguid: null };

    }
    componentWillMount(){
       user = getUserData(url);
       console.log(user);
       //set state with User data
    }
```

I've the following import statements in my React component.

```
import User from '../models/user';
import '../api/util';
```

Both my user and function getUserData are undefined. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the url param come from? And have you tried to import your function via destruction? `import { getUserData } from '../api/util';` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code `user = getUserData(url)` is setting user to a fetch promise. You need to also setup a resolver there. I would write it like

```
componentWillMount(){
 let user; 
 // getUserData actually returns a promise. resolve with a .then and set user to result
getUserData(url).then((result) => {
 user = result;

 console.log(user); // user should be defined here

 // not sure if user is a state object or not but if it is set it like this
 this.setState({user: user})
 })
}
```

Comment: This helps, but just curious, does the setting state have to be inside the then().

Comment: yes, because getUserData is an asynchronous function meaning javascript will execute it and immediately go to the next thing before the promise resolves and the results are back which will cause user to be undefined. Anytime you are dealing with ajax calls related to state you need to make sure to setState within .then or else you will get undefined.